# telegram bot node.js настройка яркости пк

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Подскажите как при помощи телеграм бота регулировать яркость на пк. При помощи консольной программы и 
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
научил бота писать консольные команды для регуляции звука. Может что-то подобное с яркостью сделать можно?

Comment: Решение по nodejs и telegram таки уже у вас есть, дальше все зависит от os, стоит ее указать в вопросе.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+monitor+brightness+control